# secure security (Https) issue in opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have done secure security(https) in my website if I open my website means it is showing like (http://www.kuberansilks.in/), but just one-time refresh means https is taking I need if I open my site means it will open starting stage please help me (I'm using aws server).

my htaccess code below please check it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kuberansilks\.in [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kuberansilks.in/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Check your config file for `HTTPS_SERVER`and make sure the address includes is set to `https://www.kuberansilks.in/`

### Option 2

Enable SSL via the OpenCart 2 Admin. Go to `Settings > Server > Use SSL` and set this to **YES**

### Option 3

Force SSL. In your config file change the line that defines `HTTP_SERVER` to include an SSL version of your website. 

From: `define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.kuberansilks.in/');` 
To: `define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.kuberansilks.in/');`

### Option 4

edit your htaccess file to force all traffic to an http version of the site. [link to google search](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=htaccess%20force%20https)